# How to Validation phone number to allow the white spaces, (),+ and - symbols using Visual force Page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How to Validation phone number to allow the white spaces, (),+ and - symbols using Visual force Page? Please give me any examples using java script.

Comment: You can find countless resources on JS validation and regular expressions through a quick Google search. Did you look into this at all?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this in VF or Javascript? Salesforce has a great metadata-driven validation engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to perform your validation.

```
function phonenumber(yourPhoneNumber) {
  var regexExpression= '/^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/';
  if(yourPhoneNumber.value.match(regexExpression)) {
    // do your processing here
  }  
  else {  
    alert("Wrond Phone number!!!");

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nitin,  I am implementing your code, But this is allowed text. I don't want allowed text and any special characters. only allowed numbers,+,- and spaces etc.,